# best way to resolve a datagrid population issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, deserialization

Please I'd appreciate it very much if someone could help me with this, it's been 4 days and still, with my knowledge in c# I can't solve this.

I need some guide.

So I deserialize an XML document and I have a structure like this:

```
public class ServiceConfig
{
    public List<DatabaseDescriptor> Databases { get; set; }  
}

public class DatabaseDescriptor
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Table> Tables { get; set; }        
}

public class Table
{  
    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("TableName")]
    public string TableName { get; set; }
}
public xml.ServiceConfig xmlData { get; set; }
```

I'm struggling a lot, I tried Datagridviews, Datatables and so on, for something which apparently is simple.

I have a datagrid that gets populated from the `DatabaseDescriptor` object, and when I click on the cell of the database T should get it's tables from the `Table` object.

I need to be able to add tables because I need to store data in memory and then in the end I need to serialize to an xml again.

How do I do the part of getting respective data tables for each database?
Please if you can't help me, avoid sarcastic or ironic comments.

Comment: Now which?? Winform's DataGridView or WPF's DataGrid or ASP's DataGrid??? Please be specific and precise! And tag your question accordingly! Did you do the Serializing? If so, where is the code?

Comment: @TaW yes, A WPF DataaGrid, and yes, i already did the serializing, it's ok, i just need a way to put the data as i need it

Comment: -1. Close-voting. **Unclear what you're asking.** - It is not clear from your question / comments whether you're struggling with showing the records in a DataGrid, doing a Master/Detail kind of thing, or trying to fry some eggs. Please post *specific* information about the *specific* problem you're having with a *specific* task, and the *specific* things you already tried and the *specific* ways in which whatever you tried isn't working.

Comment: How is your XAML? Post the XAML please. This is usually solved with Data Bindings, and requires you to bind the correct properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is it that you're actually struggling with? Visual representation of your data structure in WPF?
If your trying to display the child elements in some meaningful way you could use `TreeView` like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Databases}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myTypes:DatabaseDescriptor}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tables}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myTypes:Table}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TableName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Or use `DataGrid` with specified `DataTemplate` maybe? Or even two separate `DataGrid` controls so the second one displays child elements upon row selection of the other.